# Cumulative user ratings

Tags: 7, flags, rating

I am trying to set up a user to user rating system where users can rate nodes and the average is the users rating / total feedback.

I was thinking about using fivestar to create a field on the user profile, then create a fivestar reference (which doesnt exist to my knowledge) to that field so when a user rates a node they aren't rating the node, but the user's rating field attached to their user profile.

Is their a way to get users to rate nodes authored by a user and have it total up to give the user the average rating? I wanted something easy and light without having to create a feedback content type with a fivestar field and using entity prepopulate to pull the user in to link the user to the review content type. Or do it with entityforms/webform.

Would this be doable with flag since I am already using it pretty extensively?

Thanks.

Comment: Is what you really want to have viewer user rate the author user when they are looking at node?(though to the viewer user it will appear they are rating the node). Or do you need the ratings on the nodes too.

Comment: I am looking for having a user rating on the user but allow users to rate the user while looking at their nodes. The node that is being viewed isn't getting rated, but the user. Basically, I want the users node to show, have users rate the user (author) without having to go to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what you can do:

1. Attach a Five Star field to the user
2. Create Views block that shows the users. Select to show fields and only show the Five star field.
3. Use a contextual filter in the View to filter by User Id(uid). Select "Provide a Default Argument" -> "User id from URL" -> "Also look for a node and use the node author"
4. Place this block on the page. Restrict it by content type if you want.
5. When someone Views a node then they will see the Views block also and can rate the user.

You could put Header text area in text in the View to give the user instructions. You could also display the user name, picture or other information if you wanted.

This is way I could think of with the least amount of modules. If you were already using Panels you could use Panels to place the Five Star field on the node page but I won't suggest installing Panels just for this use case.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Thank you for the help.

I wonder if entityreference would work in this case as well. That way you wouldn't need a separate block on the page. You could create the fivestar on the user page, then use entityreference to "link" or "show" the users fivestar field on the node itself.

I will have to test out a few things. But thanks again for the detailed response.

Comment: What would you make the reference or "link" to? You shouldn't have to make an entityreference from the node to author itself because there is already an explicit reference because they are the author.